# jQuery AJAX Recursively

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### Background

I have made a PHP script that sends an email to many users by looping through the users' ID via POST. When I try using the script with a lot of users (1000+), the script times out.

To resolve this, I decided to use AJAX on the front end that sends each request individually. I have set up a simple sample page to test my code. The PHP script delays for five seconds. I would expect to get a request per five seconds. However, I am getting a delay of five seconds, and then all of the responses at once. With more research, I discovered that my AJAX calls are chaining, which is not what I want. Rather, I would only like to send the next request when the last AJAX call was completed.

### Code

#### HTML

```
<form id='frmAjax' method='post' action='run_form.php'>
    <span>1</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test1'><br>
    <span>2</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test2'><br>
    <span>3</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test3'><br>
    <span>4</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test4'><br>
    <span>5</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test5'><br>
    <span>6</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test6'><br>
    <span>7</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test7'><br>
    <span>8</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test8'><br>
    <span>9</span><input type="checkbox" name='option' value='test9'><br>

    <input id='btnAjax' type='button' value='Submit AJAX'>
</form>
```

#### Javascript Code

```
$("#btnAjax").click(function() {
    var options = $("#frmAjax input:checkbox:checked");

    $(options).each(function(i) {
        var postData = {option: $(options[i]).val()};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            url: "run_ajax.php", 
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            statusCode: {
                500: function() {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

#### PHP Code

```
<?
    echo("Success on ".$_POST["option"].".");
    sleep(5);
?>
```

### Question

My question is this, how can I make my AJAX calls recursive, not sending the next request until the previous has finished?

Comment: why don't you send a new request in the success of the first one

Comment: Are you sending a single user for each request?

Comment: @Taplar Yes, the JavaScript would be sending the ID to the PHP script.

Comment: @saurabhyadav How could I do that recursively, in a loop?

Comment: "1000+" immediately makes me think [`max_input_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) issue. Default is 1000 usually.

Comment: @ficuscr Attempting a large number gave me a timeout error. I am trying to avoid a timeout error.

Comment: one more thing you can do is send all the id at once and send the response from the PHP file  before executing the rest of the code if it suits you i can help you with that

Comment: I would highly suggest you send them all at once and have the script do the looping, not the javascript.  Forcing the user to make 1000+ ajax requests for an operation is kinda crazy.

Comment: Also, did you mean [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion&spell=1)?

Comment: @ficuscr you say "Build you post data, then send it once." Can you give an example? I'm not understanding how this would resolve my timeout issue.

Comment: They're not "chaining" - they're all been sent at the same time and your php adds a fake delay.   No doubt this delay is to simulate the queue, but if you have 1000 emails, it'll take an hour and half to send them all... hope you have a nice progress bar on your UI! :)

Comment: @Taplar Can you please explain how sending them all at once would resolve me issue? When I sent all of them at once and looped in PHP, I would receive a timeout error.

Comment: The suggestion is based upon every request is going to encounter time loss due to network latency and travel time, not to mention the over head for each request making the handshakes and all that.  Doing it as a single request is simply more performant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this one, you were not so far anyway ;)

```
function sendMail($options){
    if (!$options.length) return;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "run_ajax.php",
        data: {option:$options.eq(0).val()},
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function(){
                console.log("Error")
            }
        }
    }).always(function(){
        sendMail($options.slice(1))
    });
}

$("#btnAjax").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sendMail($("#frmAjax input:checkbox:checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `success` function and call the next `ajax` request like something like this:

```
let optionsLength = 0;
let optionsCount = 0;
$("#btnAjax").click(function() {
   optionsLength = $("#frmAjax input:checkbox:checked").length;
   callAjax();
});

function callAjax() {
 let postData = {option: $(options[optionsLength-optionsCount]).val()};
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        url: "run_ajax.php", 
        success: function(result) {
            optionsCount = optionsCount + 1;
            callAjax();
        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function() {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this is somewhat pseudo code, you will probably have to tweak it but it should give you a good idea I hope..

Answer (score 0):

Some points to help I hope :

- For your PHP script timeout, you can venture into `set_time_limit(0)` for endless script running.
- For your responses that seems simultaneous. Your PHP is probably multi-threaded, so it will treat each request in parallel and, therefore, you'll receive each response 5s after each request have been sent. The solution is, as you're pointing, to delay each request sending.

For your case, simply create a queue but better use complete callback if you don't want the process to stop at the first error :

```
$("#btnAjax").click(function() {
    function process(i) {
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: queue[i],
            url: "run_ajax.php", 
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            statusCode: {
                500: function() {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            },
            complete: {
              if(i++ < (queue.length - 1) process(i);
            }
        });
    }

    var queue = [];
    var options = $("#frmAjax input:checkbox:checked");    
    $(options).each(function(i) queue.push({option: $(options[i]).val()});    
    process(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean by pass all your data about what is checked in one request. Pass the whole form. The overhead you introduce sending one value at a time makes no sense.

```
$("#btnAjax").click(function() {

   var myform = document.getElementById("frmAjax");
   var fd = new FormData(myform);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        url: "run_ajax.php", 
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function() {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Your server side code then of course needs to handle iterating over the set of data.

If you need to know the individual outcomes of what transpires on the server then have your `rux_ajax.php` script return JSON with that detail.

Comment: How would this resolve my timeout issue? Is timing out due to it being in browser? Does accessing the script over AJAX resolve this?

Comment: Your question says you want to "chain" 1000s of calls together (perform them asynchronously). How long does each request take to finish? How long then would the whole thing take to run? If your server side code has a timeout issue then troubleshoot that independently of this client side code. For all intents and purposes the server side will execute the same way regardless if invoked from Ajax, or pulled up directly in your web browser.